# Spring OAuth2 pass state parameter

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, alexa-skills-kit

im working on an application which has to support OAuth2 for Account-Linking with Amazon Alexa (Smart home skill).

So i researched the web and started using Spring for that and it works fine, my Android app can easily obtain access_tokens and fetch data.

Now... according to the Amazon Alexa Account-Linking docs the App will pass an "state" parameter which has to be passed to the redirect_uri.
For more clearity here is the direct link to the documentation: https://developer.amazon.com/de/docs/account-linking/configure-authorization-code-grant.html#authorization-url-parameters

Anyways i have no clue how to achieve this and i hope someone here can help me here because it starts to drive me crazy

Answer (score 1):

As per my experiences, **state** parameter is nothing but one random number or string which are used to maintaining the state between application and IDP server during authentication performed. I had also used this parameter in one of my projects. You can create any random string for passing state parameter value and ensure that you will get same state parameter value in callback/redirect after authentication done.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, actually it passed the state parameter it was an error by amaon i had to put my skill into Beta testing for amazon to link my account.